# Bash custom flags with aliases or functions

Tags: bash, shell-script, bashrc

What I want is to be able to define custom flags for bash commands/aliases. For example, I have:

```
alias ll='ls -Alh'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -lh'
```

However, I want to set up a custom flag, such as -d, which will also  execute `ls -d */` on whenever I run the above commands, as such `ll -f` which would list only hidden directories in a detailed list.

Comment: aliases don't support spaces and so the best you could do would be to alias "ll-f" as oppsed to "ll -f"

Comment: Use a function instead. Much more capable than simple aliases.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what you want with your last sentence, sorry ;)

I'm assuming you want `ll` to have the functionality of `ls -Alh` *except* when it is called by `ll -f` - in that case it should only list hidden directories. If that's not what you were looking for, it should be relatively easy to adjust. Just add all your flags that have special meaning to the `getopts` command, and then write a case for each of those flags. The default case should always be `break`, so that if you pass a flag that doesn't have a special meaning for your function, then `ls -Alh` gets executed.

In any case, here's a script you can source to define a function called `ll` (aliases are not powerful to do what you want). You must **source**, i.e. `source <script>` the script, so the function gets defined. Be careful to do `unalias ll` before sourcing the script or unexpected things might happen.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
ll() {
    while getopts ":f" opt; do
        case $opt in
            f)
                command ls -Ald .*/
                return 0
                ;;
            \?)
                break;
        esac
    done
    command ls -Alh "$@"
}
```

This will cause `ll -f` to behave as `ls -Ald .*/` which lists all hidden directories. If you give `ll` a flag that is *not* `-f` it will default to call `ls -Alh "$@"` (`$@` simply stands for "all arguments"). For example, if you write `ll -d Desktop`, `ls -Alhd Desktop` will get executed.  If no flags are passed to `ll`, it will just execute `ls -Alh "$@"`.